# Selecting array key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, search, key

I've searched Google and the PHP docs but have yet to find a solution for this.  E.g. supposing I want to perform a strstr() on all the keys of an array to determine for which keys are closest to what I'm searching for, such that:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
   if(@strstr(key($array[$i]), "$search")) {
     print "Found: ". key($array[$i]). "<br>";
   }
 }
```

"key($array[$i])" is a placeholder for whatever function or means required for selecting array keys as elements to perform a strstr() upon.

Any help is appreciated sincerely.

Answer (score 2):

Use **foreach** to iterate through **Key,Value** Pair.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
   if(@strstr($key, "$search")) {
     print "Found: ". $key. "<br>";
   }
 }
```

More reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Update to answer comment:

you can use

> array_keys — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Thanks! Of curiosity though, is there a way to accomplish this via a for loop instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(strstr($key, $search))
    {
         print "Found: ". $key. "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it...

```
$found = array_filter(
                     array_keys($array), 
                     function($key) use ($search) {
                         return strpos($key, $search) !== FALSE;
                     });
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/SO3ceL).

`$found` will be an array of all keys which included a substring of which is contained in `$search`.

If you are merely looking for the presence of a string inside of another, use `strpos()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to pull out the desired keys in one step, e.g. using [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep).

```
$keys = preg_grep('/'.preg_quote($search, '/').'/', array_keys($array));

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo "Found $key<br>";
}
```